# Wordpress Multisite: Mobile theme on its own wordpress install reading / sync with main database

Tags: wordpress

- I don't want to use any plugin that redirect to mobile version (as theme is not activated and brings in lots of issues)

For now i made a new network site for the mobile theme, but when going to a post its going to the main site theme (and if i add plugin to forward main site to mobile version it kinda of works, but brings in many issues).

So best sulotion would be to have exact same replica of the main multisite wordpress on a subdomain, just with mobile theme activated for all sites in network..

problem how i can i do it?also to keep posts on mobile version in sync with the main site?

Many thanks!
and hope i was clear..

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to run a WP Multisite - you can share users and the Wordpress install, but the posts, meta values, etc are in separate tables. If you want to run the site on a single content repository (your posts), same users, etc but just with a different theme at different domains, I would use multiple installs pointed to the same database with the mobile site pointing to a different domain by overriding the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITE_URL` constants and a filter on `get_option()` (using `'option_' . $option` where `$option` is `template`, `stylesheet`, and `current_theme`) to override the theme that is loaded - look at your database values with the mobile them selected to figure out what values you want to return. You have the issue of keeping the code updated between the two installs, which shouldn't be too hard to accomplish with version control (which is a good idea anyway), using a different repository for the file on the mobile site that overrides the option values, an `@include` perhaps.

Comment: currently i have 8 sites inside the wordpress multisite.so as your suggestion to make a subdomain, copy wordpress files (but use same DB) and in the wp-config to add the WP_SITE_URL? is there a way also to define the theme from the config?as far its defined in the Database.

Comment: A possible problem would be that certain plugins which are activated on main site would affect the mobile theme in the subdomain

Comment: Oh and regarding keeping the code updated, do you mean wordpress files (not including media / theme files)?

Comment: I keep everything in my version control... if you already have a multisite install then this won't work for you. I did write a plugin that will let you [set `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITE_URL` for MultiSite](http://justin.ag/technology/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-wp-server-migration/) but another option for multisite might be to remove the `prefix_ID_(users|usermeta|posts|postmeta)` tables and replace them with views to the multisite install you want to use.

Comment: other safe solution would be 2 Domains, 2 WP Multisite, 2 DB, however i am not sure how to sync categories and posts of each site(in 'DomainA')to the corresponding site, category, post at 'DomainB', somewhere i saw that for this i need kinda of 'FeedWordPress' like plugin on DomainB

Comment: That would work too, but there are drawbacks as well - comments for example would not be synced.

Comment: what about a MySQL Cron that replicates the posts tables? :)

Comment: ^ using a view would be fewer moving parts and realtime

Comment: I'm not familiar with the view, is it a plugin?

Comment: can you please direct me for post or mor information on how i do this?Copy WP install on DomainB, wp-config use same DB use the plugin you mentioned to seto WP_HOME and then?

Comment: ok i sorted it out for now using the RSS import (FeedWordPress)